# Computing cumulative proportions from samples

Tags: r, quantile, cdf

I want to compute cumulative proportions of samples.

```
R> x=c(92, 3, 1, 4, 15, 4)
R> ecdf(x)(x)
[1] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.6666667
```

The above is a way to compute cumulative proportions as shown in the first figure. I think it is for type 7 as the default type of `quantile()` is of type 7.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/05/24/definitions-sample-quantiles.html

But I don't find an easy way to compute cumulative proportions for other types. Is thre a function in R to compute cumulative proportions from samples of all the 9 types?

Comment: If you just type in ecdf in the console of Rstudio, you can see that ecdf is not using any quantile function but something based on `cumsum(tabulate(match(x, vals)))/n`. If you want to use the quantile-function, you could take the ecdf function as an example and modify this part integrating the quantile function with type=x.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can anybody provide a solution to the question?